Axis extent option doesn't set default subchart for timeseries axis
I'm beginner with billboard.js.
I have a big payload of data starting from 1980 and ending to now (2024). I want to first show only the last 10 years of the data and then being able to zoom out or in.
From what I understand on the billboard doc, I have to use the axis.x.extent option to set a default subchart.
But nothing happens, whatever I do with the extent option nothing is changing on my graph.
Any ideas of how I could do what I'm trying to do ?
Here is a code example
// base css
import 'billboard.js/dist/theme/insight.css';
import bb from 'billboard.js';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

// for ESM environment, need to import modules as:
// import bb, {area, zoom} from "billboard.js"

var chart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    json: {
      Temperature: [
        '29.39',
        '29.7',
        '29.37',
        '28.87',
        '28.62',
        '27.72',
        '27.61',
        '27.82',
        '27.48',
        '26.78',
        '26.62',
        '26.64',
        '26.29',
        '26.01',
        '25.84',
        '25.07',
        '24.85',
        '24.01',
        '23.83',
        '22.8',
        '23',
        '22.64',
        '22.77',
        '22.64',
        '22.64',
        '22.62',
        '22.51',
        '21.42',
        '21.18',
        '20.93',
        '20.66',
        '20.48',
        '20.7',
        '21.24',
        '22.14',
        '22.78',
        '23.43',
        '23.16',
        '27.48',
        '26.78',
        '26.62',
        '26.64',
        '26.29',
        '26.01',
        '25.84',
        '25.07',
        '24.85',
        '24.01',
      ],
      x: [
        '01-01-2015',
        '02-01-2015',
        '03-01-2015',
        '04-01-2015',
        '05-01-2015',
        '06-01-2015',
        '07-01-2015',
        '08-01-2015',
        '09-01-2015',
        '10-01-2015',
        '11-01-2015',
        '12-01-2015',
        '01-01-2016',
        '02-01-2016',
        '03-01-2016',
        '04-01-2016',
        '05-01-2016',
        '06-01-2016',
        '07-01-2016',
        '08-01-2016',
        '09-01-2016',
        '10-01-2016',
        '11-01-2016',
        '12-01-2016',
        '01-01-2017',
        '02-01-2017',
        '03-01-2017',
        '04-01-2017',
        '05-01-2017',
        '06-01-2017',
        '07-01-2017',
        '08-01-2017',
        '09-01-2017',
        '10-01-2017',
        '11-01-2017',
        '12-01-2017',
        '01-01-2018',
        '02-01-2018',
        '03-01-2018',
        '04-01-2018',
        '05-01-2018',
        '06-01-2018',
        '07-01-2018',
        '08-01-2018',
        '09-01-2018',
        '10-01-2018',
        '11-01-2018',
        '12-01-2018',
      ],
    },
    type: 'area', // for ESM specify as: area()
    xFormat: '%m-%d-%Y',
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      tick: {
        fit: false,
        count: 5,
      },
      type: 'timeseries',
      extent: ['12-01-2016', '12-01-2018'],
    },
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true, // for ESM specify as: zoom()
  },
  tooltip: {
    format: {
      title: function (x) {
        return d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d')(x);
      },
    },
  },
  point: {
    focus: {
      only: true,
    },
  },
  bindto: '#xAxisTickTimeseries',
});

Here is a stackblitz of the example
Thank you
